# How can i add environment variables in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I have added environment variables to the PATH in windows that hosts Jenkins. But i want the equivalent in Jenkins.

I have tried adding it to global variables but no luck.
The issue I get is

```
 exec: "signtool": executable file not found in %PATH%:
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for the [Environment Injector Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/envinject/)

Comment: not sure how this helps.. In windows i can set the path to the signtool. In Jenkins how can i do the same ? cause it cant find it .. it seems Jenkins does not have the path set?

Comment: you need to set it to the environment within jenkins - for that purpose there is the linked plugin

Comment: Is it the %Path% environment variable ? Can i set a name of lets say SMCTL and put the path for the .exe ?